# yield in python == yield return in C#?

Tags: c#, python, iterator, return, yield

I haven't been able to find any info on using JUST yield in C# (when used for a generator).
Is this because C# always uses yield *with* return? (yield return Object)

I think I'm confusing myself since I was learning the same topic (generators) in python today aswell, and so far i've only seen yield used alone in Python..

Comment: Per [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx), the only other C# option is `yield break`. Bare `yield` isn't correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`yield` keyword is introduced by C# 2.0 in order to implement iteartion easier. On the other hand it has some disadventages. Let's first look at the yield keyword.

```
public IEnumerable GetPowersofTwo()
{
   for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
       yield return (int)System.Math.Pow(2, i);
   yield break;
}
```

It is just a C# language feature. During compilation Compiler converts yield method and its class to instances of `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator` implemented classes.

**Criticism of the keyword `yield`**

`yield` has a couple of drawbacks first of all it is designed to simplify implementing iterations. But it can be used to write very ill designed code (like goto). But using it for other than the intended purpose will make your code hard to follow. Second problem is that "yield" does not make sense in Object Oriented paradigm just like delegates.

Comment: BTW: `yield break` is not necccessary after the loop.

Comment: Ans is based on "I haven't been able to find any info on using JUST yield in C#". why negative.